# Why can not I convert a string to DateTime?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, web-services, datetime

I can not convert this string, can anyone help me?

```
[WebMethod]
public void InsertUsuario(string usuario, string senha, string nome, string dtnasc, string fone, string email, int oab, string endereco, string bairro, string cep, int codcidade, string cpf, string cnpj)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
    {
        string chav = "asfasdf";
        DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(dtnasc, "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT Into Usuarios (IdUsuario, Usuario, Senha, Nome, Chave, DtNasc, Fone, Email, OAB, Endereco, Bairro, CEP, CodCidade, CPF, CNPJ) VALUES ((Select MAX(idusuario)+1 from Usuarios), '" + usuario + "', '" + senha + "', '" + nome + "', '" + chav + "', '"+d+ "', '" + fone + "', '" + email + "', " + oab + ", '" + endereco + "', '" + bairro + "', '" + cep + "', " + codcidade + ", '" + cpf  + "','"+cnpj+"')");

        //command.Parameters.Add("@dtnasc", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
        command.Connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

This is the error that appears:

> System.FormatException: Cadeia de caracteres não foi reconhecida como DateTime válido.
>   em System.DateTimeParse.ParseExact(String s, String format, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles style)
>   em OniPresenteAPI.oni.InsertUsuario(String usuario, String senha, String nome, String dtnasc, String fone, String email, Int32 oab, String endereco, String bairro, String cep, Int32 codcidade, String cpf, String cnpj)

Comment: *Please* use parameterized SQL.  You are **wide open** to SQL Injection attacks.  Not only that, but if you used parameterized SQL, it might even fix this issue, since concatenating strings together to form a SQL script is extremely prone to breaking with errors exactly like the one you're getting.

Comment: Apart from sql injection issue, what string cannot be parsed? You haven't even shown an example.

Comment: What is the exact value of dtnasc?

Comment: What exactly does the date time that you are passing in look like? Using the `DateTime.ParseExact()` method requires you to match that format exactly. You currently have single quotes wrapping each of the sections within your DateTime string with the exception of the beginning and the end, so I suppose _that_ could be an issue, but without an example, we are just guessing...

Comment: The value I am trying to pass is this: "1991-12-21 00:00"

Comment: @KatheQuandt, i presume "1991-12-21 00:00"  is being passed into DateTime.ParseExact()?

Answer (score 0):

The issue based on the comment that you are passing s date string of **"1991-12-21 00:00"** into `DateTime.ParseExact()`. The clue is in the Exception which is blowing up because the second parameters `format` parameter is incorrect.

Your parameter was `"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm"`. The correct format should be `"yyyy-M-dd hh:mm"`. Have a read of the documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131038%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), specifically this area:

> The
>   DateTime.ParseExact(String, String, IFormatProvider, DateTimeStyles)
>   method parses the string representation of a date, which must be in a
>   format defined by the format parameter. It also requires that the date
>   and time elements in s appear in the order specified by format. If s
>   does not match the pattern of the format parameter, with any
>   variations defined by the style parameter, the method throws a
>   FormatException.

Here is my working example:

```
using System;
using  System.Globalization;
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string dateAsAString = "1991-12-21 00:00";
        try
        {   
            DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(dateAsAString, "yyyy-M-dd hh:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
            Console.WriteLine("The correct Date is " + d.ToString());
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} is not in the correct format.", dateAsAString);
        }
    }
}
```

A working [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/amziHj) as well for you to play around with the `format` string.